# Working with Git and phpDesigner

Tags: git, editor, phpdesigner

I have just begun to use git as a versioning tool. I have set almost everything up successfully but the code editor. Now I use phpDesigner but all the config options I have seen so far do not use phpDesigner. I have followed some instructions to get `git config --global core.editor phpDesigner` but when I try to commit, git is still saying `Syntax error near unexpected token '(' There was a problem with the editor`. I develop on Windows and my phpDesigner copy is installed in `C:\Program Files (x86)`. Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the brackets in the path to your editor are causing the problem.

Are you putting the editor target in quotes?

e.g.:

```
git config --global core.editor "C:\Program Files (x86)..."
```